# Empty guid id in QueueTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, queuetrigger

Every `id` I receive from queue has the value "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" rather than for example:

[image: random_id]

Here is my code:

```
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
[Singleton("{Path}", SingletonScope.Function, Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
public async Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("externalQueue", Connection = ConfigurationConstants.ConnectionString)]
        BaseQueueRequest req,
        ILogger logger,
        string id)
{
    // ...
}
```

I created this topic because solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042405/how-to-get-the-queue-messageid-inside-the-queue-trigger-function) does not work for me.

For service bus trigger it worked fine, but when I switched to `QueueTrigger` and changed `messageId` to `Id`, but I always receive a bad id.

My question is how can I receive real ID from the message?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from end, this is working fine for me when I configure connection string as below in my `local.settings.json`.

When connecting to cloud storage:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "constre",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "constre": "<CONNECTIONSTRING>"
  }
}
```

When connecting to local storage:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

Below is my `function.json`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp9
{
    public class Function3
    {
        [FunctionName("Function3")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "constre")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, I have configured connection string using Connected services as below.

[image]

[image]